# how to develop iphone app using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

I new to iPhone development. I am working on an iPhone app using the `phonegap` framework. I created a tableview using HTML code. That HTML code is not working in Xcode4.3. However, it does working in the browser.

How can I run the HTML code in xcode using phonegap.

Comment: Work through their tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

for latest cordova-2.0 -
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

for cordova 1.9 - 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0rc1/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

for designing the web layout for phone http://codiqa.com/ this site may help you

Thanks